# Return from a Function within a Closure

Tags: swift, closures, return-value, swift2

Why is it that in `case 1`, my function returns with `["reached end": "reached end"]` not the value of the response dictionary? How can I make it return with the value of `responseDictionary`?

*Background: `HelperClass.doMath` takes a number and has a completion block that returns a dictionary*

```
func handleTask(task: [String: AnyObject]) -> AnyObject {
    switch task {
    case 1:
        if let bigNumber = task[bigNumberKey] as? NSNumber {
            HelperClass.doMath(bigNumber, replyBlock: {(responseDictionary: [NSObject: AnyObject]!) -> Void in
                return [responseDictionary]
            })
        }
    case 2:
        return 2
    case 3:
        return 3
    default:
        break
    }

    return ["reached end": "reached end"]
}
```

Comment: When working with asynchronous code you have to use callbacks, not return. So your `handleTask` also needs a block analogous to `replyBlock` to call when you get `responseDictionary`

Comment: Hmm - it is asynchronous actually.

Comment: Is the closure executed synchronously or asynchronously? If it is synchronous, why do you use a closure?

Comment: @lxx Sounds about right - How could I rewrite handleTask to do that?

Comment: Your code has some really weird parts. Does it really compile? Your `switch task` works on dictionary, but you are checking for values 1, 2 and 3. 1, 2, or 3 are not a dictionary. Also, your `replyBlock` accepts dictionary and returns void, but you are attempting to return array of dictionaries `[responseDictionary]`. I think you should look into these things and make sure that the code is doing what you really want.

Comment: @MirekE You're right - I just used 1,2,3 to simplify the code for SO. replyBlock makes a network request and responseDictionary is the payload. So it would make sense that it return nothing, no?

Comment: Ah, ok. I don't know what you want to return in the replyBlock, however you declare it as returning Void and you are returning `[responseDictionary]`, which is array of dictionaries with one dictionary inside... In any case, `doMath` will run asynchronously and `handleTask` will return immediately (before it is finished) with `["reached end":"reached end"]`. If you want to get the result of asynchronous `doMath`, you will need to use different approach.

Comment: @TheodoreHaden you basically have to make your `handleTask` return void, and provide the result using a callback/block instead. So you remove all return and add a new parameter, which is a function that accepts what you want to return as a parameter...analogous to `replyBlock` as I said.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
func handleTask(task: [String: AnyObject]) -> AnyObject {
    switch task {
    case 1:
        if let bigNumber = task[bigNumberKey] as? NSNumber {
            return HelperClass.doMath(bigNumber, replyBlock: {(responseDictionary: [NSObject: AnyObject]!) -> Void in
                return [responseDictionary]
            })
        }
    case 2:
        return 2
    case 3:
        return 3
    default:
        break
    }

    return ["reached end": "reached end"]
}
```

Your closure `replyBlock` is being passed to the `doMath` method of `HelperClass`, and being used there for some purpose. It is executed in the scope of your `handleTask` function. Therefore `return [responseDictionary]` brings you back to the scope of your `case 1`, and doesn't cause `handleTask` to return anything.
What you're trying to do though (I assume) is return the result of this function. This can be achieved by simply adding a return in front of the method-call, which will in turn return any result `doMath` yields.